# How to add wiringPi library with cmake on vscode?

Tags: ubuntu, c++, cmake, raspberry-pi, vscode

I tried a few things but I am not so knowlegable about it.
I tried with cmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(wpitest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

# Include headers
include_directories(.)


#here
link_directories(wiringPi)

#target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} wiringPi)
```

for the blink.cpp file :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <wiringPi.h>

// LED Pin - wiringPi pin 0 is BCM_GPIO 17.

#define LED 4

int main ()
{
  while (1)
  {
      printf ("Raspberry Pi blink\n") ;
wiringPiSetupGpio();
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT) ;
    digitalWrite (LED, HIGH) ;  // On
    delay (50) ;        // mS
    digitalWrite (LED, LOW) ;   // Off
    delay (50) ;
  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the lib installed
`sudo apt-get install wiringpi`

And try
`find_library`
and
`target_link_libraries`

*If you use rpi4, build from github source maybe required.

Comment: yeah that worked thank you